# Named multi_match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a hand here. I have a cross_fields multi_match query and I need to use named queries for each field. I can rewrite it into a bool/should match but then I dont know how to reproduce the cross_fields condition. Any idea? Thanks!

Multimatch query: Relevance OK, but no named queries

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "example_query",
      "fields": ["name","lastname"],
      "type": "cross_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Bool query: Named queries OK but bad relevance

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "example query",
              "_name": "name_match"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "latname": {
              "query": "example query",
              "_name": "latname_match"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does using `dismax` with `tie_breaker: 1.0` work for your ES index?

Something like this:

```
GET vehicle/_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "tie_breaker": 1.0,
      "queries": [
        {
          "match": {
            "make": {
              "query": "Lamborghini",
              "_name": "make"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "model": {
              "query": "Diablo",
              "_name": "model"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The [Dismax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html#query-dsl-dis-max-query-top-level-params) query is very similar to the `multi_match` query in that it compares scores across sub clauses/queries. The `tie_breaker` parameter controls how much losing/non-max fields contributed to the final summation of clause scores, any losing fields scores are multiplied by the `tie_breaker`. The default `tie_breaker: 0.0`, which is most similar to `type: best_fields` in `multi_match`.

Comment: Thanks Nate, it worked. The score is not exactly the same as using multi_query, but the first result is correct now using dis_max instead of should.